# Cufon Mouseover not working

Tags: css, cufon

This may be a css error but I can't figure it out for the life of me. When I mouseover the menu option "books" the Cufon replacement should change the text color to white and the background to green the background color is changing but the text color is not.

Take a look http://www.urlgone.com/340aa1/ at the menu under categories on the left side.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you show the code where you make it change color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with CSS. In CSS you have:

```
ul.dropdown a:hover { 
  color: #2a2a2a;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Change this to:

```
ul.dropdown a:hover { 
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Edit.

It's in this file: http://cs.solesu.com/skins/solesu_basic/customer/dropdown.css

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable hover:true in cufon replacement code.

Comment: Welcome to SO and if you can please add some code example to explain your solution.